# How can I call a stored procedure in EF Core on entity with query filters?

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

We are using Query Filters in EF Core 7 to handle soft-deleted records. Unfortunately, when I call a stored procedure using `.FromSql("mysproc")`, it gives me the following error...

> InvalidOperationException: 'FromSql' or 'SqlQuery' was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it. Consider calling 'AsEnumerable' after the method to perform the composition on the client side.

This `TextValues.IgnoreQueryFilters().FromSql($"MySproc {myparam}")` doesn't work because `FromSql()` is not defined on IQueryable (the code does not compile).

This `MyObjects.FromSql("MySproc").IgnoreQueryFilters()` compiles, but produces the same error. I'm pretty sure that `IgnoreQueryFilters()` needs to be first.

The stored procedure does return data for `MyObject`, so I would like to use the `MyObjects` property, if possible.

Currently, my only idea is to add a 2nd property without a filter, but this isn't ideal. I would prefer not making an unfiltered property available.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyObjects.FromSql("MySproc").IgnoreQueryFilters()` should work.

Here's a compete example with EF Core 7.0.3

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;


using var db = new Db();

db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
db.Database.EnsureCreated();

db.Database.ExecuteSql($"create proc get_foo @n varchar(20) as select * from Foo");

var a = "a";
var c1 = db.Set<Foo>().FromSql($"exec get_foo {a}").IgnoreQueryFilters().ToList();
var c2 = db.Set<Foo>().ToList();


Console.WriteLine("Finished");


class Db : DbContext
{

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=EfCore7Test;TrustServerCertificate=true;Integrated Security=true",
            o =>
            {
                o.UseRelationalNulls();
            })
            .LogTo(m => Console.WriteLine(m), LogLevel.Information);
        optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().HasQueryFilter( e => e.Name == "foo");

    }


}


[Table("Foo")]
public class Foo 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

outputs

```
info: 2/16/2023 18:54:00.134 RelationalEventId.CommandExecuted[20101] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
      Executed DbCommand (23ms) [Parameters=[p0='a' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      exec get_foo @p0
info: 2/16/2023 18:54:00.203 RelationalEventId.CommandExecuted[20101] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
      Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [f].[Id], [f].[Name]
      FROM [Foo] AS [f]
      WHERE [f].[Name] = N'foo'
Finished
```

Comment: Great answer. Thank you. I did try using the Ignore after FromSql, but it had failed with a similar message. I think the problem was that I used .SingleAsync() to get the results. Switching to .ToArrayAsync() worked.